# events.js:130 throw TypeError('listener must be a function')

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to run a node.js getting this error

```
events.js:130
throw TypeError('listener must be a function');
```

My code is,

```
var connect = require("connect");
var http = require("http");
var app = connect();
// Logging middleware
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
 console.log("In comes a " + request.method + " to " + request.url);
 next();
});

// Send "hello world"
app.use(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
response.end("Hello world!\n");
});
http.createServer(app).listen(1337);
```

Now execute this code on terminal as `node app.js` I get an error

```
events.js:130
throw TypeError('listener must be a function');
      ^
TypeError: listener must be a function

at TypeError (<anonymous>)
at Server.EventEmitter.addListener (events.js:130:11)
at new Server (http.js:1850:10)
at Object.exports.createServer (http.js:1880:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/express/app.js:17:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

I installed node.js and express.js. How to execute this code ?

Comment: Seems the stack trace is mentioning line 17 in app.js which may or may not be shown here. It might be that the 'next' callback is missing from the second app.use. You should maybe consider app.get('*', function(req,res){}); instead

Comment: I am also facing same issue with events.js:216. I am trying to bind io.socket and binaryServer with express server. Error message is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake.

The problem is that the program(app.js) is not in the root of framework folder. I changed the location of this program to the express frameworks root folder. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: could you please explain a bit more? I am trying to use socket.io with my angular application. its showing the same error