# 500 TypeError: listener must be a function at ServerResponse.addListener

Tags: node.js, express

Based upon the voted answer [events.js:130 throw TypeError('listener must be a function')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904746/events-js130-throw-typeerrorlistener-must-be-a-function)

I am trying to implement Logging wherein we save every action in DB. To cater this, I was planning to listen to finish or close event of response stream in app.js 
I understand that I need to put this code in Express frameworks root folder.Can you please specify where exactly so that I can access listen to this event and access requested URL as well.
Below is the code snippet

```
app.use(function (req, res,next) {
    function afterResponse (req,res,next){
         console.log("Response finished from the path "+ req.url);

    }
    res.on('finish', afterResponse(req,res,next));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While the `'finish'` event emitted by the response object is not in the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html), it does exist. However, as an undocumented feature, you may want to avoid it since it could be removed anytime. Without more information about exactly what you are trying to accomplish, it's hard to say whether there might be a better alternative, although I suspect there is. With that caveat, here is the answer to your question.

If you want to capture every response, you need to define a middleware function near the top of your app, before any response has been sent (order matters in Express 4). The example you have above is too complicated; the `'finish'` event listener doesn't take parameters. Instead, you can simply do this:

```
// This example uses ES2015 syntax

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.on('finish', () => {
    console.log(`Response finished from the path ${req.url}`);
  });
  next();
});
```

The example above adds the listener *before* any request is sent, but the listener will only be called *after* the request is sent. Make sure the listener itself takes no parameters; if you pass `req` as a parameter as in your example, it will be `undefined`, which is exactly what you *don't* want. Just define your litsener in the middleware function itself, and you can access `req` or `res` as much as you like.

Alternatively, if you don't want the listener to be redefined on every request, you can access `req` through the response object itself, which is available as the `this` context within the listener:

```
// This example uses ES2015 syntax

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.on('finish', onFinish);
  next();
});

function onFinish() {
  console.log(`Response finished from the path ${this.req.url}`);
}
```

Comment: If we do not pass the req object from express to the event listener, req object will be null.
I am getting error "cannot read url property of undefined"

Comment: And if we pass req in the event listener, error encountered is "listener must be a function"

Comment: Are you using Express 4? This may well have been different in prior versions.

Comment: Could you maybe update your post or provide a link so I can get a better idea of what might be going on? I tested my own examples to make sure they work, so I'm not sure I can say much more without seeing more of your code.

Comment: By the way, the reason why the error message says `listener must be a function` in your original example is because you are calling the function, passing the *return value* of the function to `res.on()` rather than the function itself. However, if you've followed the examples I have provided, you will be passing the actual function without calling it, so you should not be getting the same error.